# Experimental Measurement of Quantum phase transition in an optical lattice

Tags: cold-atoms

In Greiner and coauthors' [seminal paper](http://greiner.physics.harvard.edu/PDF%20Files/Qunatum%20Phase%20Transistion.pdf), the cold atoms are confined in a harmonic trap.  So different many-body phases may coexist in the trap at a given lattice depth. For a deep lattice, there will be edge superfluid at the edges of the trap. My question is how to distinguish the Superfluid-Mott Insulator phase transition by the time-of-flight method if there is mixture of phases in the trap.

Comment: Maybe these two papers would be of help: [Kashurnikov et al.](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.66.031601) and [Zakrzewski](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.71.043601)